# Dont update range part of sumif when copying rows

Tags: excel

I have following in Excel:

```
=SUMIF(F2:M2;"I";F6:M6)
```

When I expand this downwwards in Excel, Excel naturally increments the row number in the formular. Is it possible to copy the formular downwards without changing the range part (F2:M2)? Would be great with a another approach than chaning this 1000 times manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean your missing the $ sign?
Press the your range in the formula bar and press the F4 button on your keyboard to toggle this setting.

```
=SUMIF($F$2:$M$2;"I";$F$6:$M$6)
```